# Бот принимающий заявки на вступление в группу

Tags: python, aiogram, бот

Есть бот который автоматически принимает заявки на вступление в группу, но нужно, чтобы он принимал заявку только того человека, чье сообщение я переслал в бота. Никак не могу понять куда смотреть и подобных вопросов не нашел.

Comment: Добавьте БД, и сохраняйте в него ид пользователя, полученное от пересланного боту сообщения. Ну а далее перед приемом заявок проверяйте, есть ли это ИД в базе или нет. Как пример, по аналогии можете что нибудь более практичное придумать

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать